# Spring integration: move file and invoke callback

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need the following flow:

- scan the folder and move incoming files from current directory to another
- invoke some callback method
- don't process a new file until the previous callback is completed
  So I need only one file in process.

I tried smth like this:

```html
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="/inbound">
  <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="/outbound"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                       output-channel="filesOut"
                       ref="handler"/>
```

But in this case handler execution happens before file move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost close to the solution!

Only the difference that you should consider to use `<publish-subscribe-channel>` for the `filesIn` without any `executor` configuration for it and the `<service-activator>` (`outbound-channel-adapter`) as a second subscriber to that channel.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="/inbound">
  <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="filesIn"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="/outbound"/>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter input-channel="filesIn" ref="handler"/>
```

Be sure that `handler` doesn't return anything with its service method.
Since there is already nowhere to send the reply.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I want! Is any solution to catch the errors, for example, if the handler throws an unexpected exception?